# Repackaging .deb with an alternate target

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I'd like to create a PPA that hosts additional builds of `binutils-cross`, as Ubuntu and Debian only provide them for common architectures (there's no official `ia64-cross` build for Trusty or Wheezy, for example).

The only change that's necessary for this is to set the contents of the `debian/target` file to the target architecture (e.g. `ia64-linux-gnu`).

After setting up a launchpad account and signing the Code of Conduct, what steps do I need to publish this?

The normal steps I'd invoke to build the software locally are, for example:

```
apt-get source binutils
cd binutils-*
export DEB_TARGET_ARCH=ia64-linux-gnu
echo ia64-linux-gnu > debian/target
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

I'm completely new to PPA and Launchpad, so I apologize if this is a silly question.

## Edit

Note that I am not asking how to build a `mips` or any foreign-architecture binary on Launchpad.  Binaries emitted in this manner are i386 or x86_64 binaries, which *themselves* can assemble/disassemble/etc for foreign architectures.

This is to build the `mips` equivalent of the [`binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=binutils).

```
$ dpkg -S $(which mips-linux-gnu-as)
binutils-mips-linux-gnu: /usr/bin/mips-linux-gnu-as
$ file $(which mips-linux-gnu-as)
/usr/bin/mips-linux-gnu-as: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=44e6366aeea6fb2b12b7e39aec2394fef86c642c, stripped
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ echo nop | mips-linux-gnu-as -
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit MSB  relocatable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Comment: @ThomasW. i386 & amd64 are it normally for builds, arm can be enabled upon request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this kind of thing you would normally just modify the source package locally in the way that you desire, tweak its version and/or name, and upload that to your PPA.  You can achieve the environment variable change by setting it in `debian/rules`.

The documentation tree at https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA answers a number of common questions in this area.

I would suggest looking into the existing `binutils-*-cross` source packages in Ubuntu (e.g. `binutils-arm64-cross`) as a model for this, though.  Those do it by build-depending on `binutils-source`.  It would probably be quickest to take whichever one of those is most up to date, search-and-replace architecture names, adjust the changelog, and upload.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of how those builds were made.  Attempting to `apt-get source binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu` just gets the `binutils` source.  It wasn't apparent that these were actually generated via `binutils-arm64-cross` for example.  It doesn't help that `binutils-arm64-cross` doesn't even show up in `apt-cache search binutils`.